# SQL Updating a particular rows based on the ID in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables

```
Price
RET_ID DBS_ID RRP

Database
DBS_ID PRO_ID
```

I would like to use UPDATE such that I can increase RRP in the Price table by 20% if the PRO_ID in the Database table is = 1

```
UPDATE
  ( SELECT RRP
    FROM PRICE
      JOIN database
        ON database.dbs_id = price.dbs_id
  )
SET rrp = 100
WHERE (database.pro_ID = 1);
```

I've been trying all manner of INNER JOIN ... ON to no avail.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the filtering condition in the `where` clause.  Here is a method using `exists`:

```
update price p
    set rpr = rpr * 1.2
    where exists (select 1
                  from database d
                  where d.dbs_id = p.dbs_id and d.pro_id = 1
                 );
```

Here is another way using `in`:

```
update price p
    set rpr = rpr * 1.2
    where p.dbs_id in (select d.dbs_id
                       from database d
                       where d.pro_id = 1
                      );
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch Gordon. It took me a while but I finally got my head around the WHERE ... IN concept. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
    UPDATE Price P SET RRP = RRP*1.2
 WHERE EXISTS 
(select  1 from Database 
where DBS_ID = P.DBS_ID AND PRO_ID = 1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Akshey.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query

```
MERGE INTO PRICE P 
 USING DATABASE D ON
(P.DBS_ID=D.DBS_ID) AND
D.PRO_ID=1
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
UPDATE SET
P.RRP=P.RRP*1.2;
```

When you are updating table from another table, always use MERGE function which is an amazing concept in SQL

Comment: Hope you go it. Any doubt, feel free to ask

Comment: Thanks a mil Jim! :)